# Cant do pull or push in Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, github, tortoisegit

Im using Git-1.7.11 and TortoiseGit-1.7.14.0 64bit .when i try to get a pull, my computer getting stuck.

after few minutes this message is shown

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this Problem?

Comment: Could you please try to pull via the git-bash and verify if the problem is still existing with the bash? If not, you have problems with your client.

Comment: Note that Git 1.7.11 is [over three years old](https://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/detail?name=git-1.7.11.tar.gz&can=2&q=) and TortoiseGit 1.7.14.0 is [two and a half years old](https://download.tortoisegit.org/tgit/1.7.14.0/). Upgrading these might help.